# Do not reopen buffers of last session

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, sessions

When Vim starts, it always opens buffers of last session too. That is to say, when I leave Vim by closing all windows, but do not explicitly close buffers (by `:bd`), those buffers will be opened next time Vim starts. How can I not open these buffers?

Comment: I find it irritating because sometimes I close Vim to edit files with other programs, or rename them. Since Vim keeps opening them, afterwards I reopen Vim, falsely thinking these files are not being opened, there will be swap files, which I must take time to deal with.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Does it behave the same when you start Vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: Oh... when I open with `vim -u NONE`, this no longer happens. I think I have to comment out my vimrc one by one, to debug the problem....

Comment: what is your 'viminfo' setting?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Do you mean: `verbose set viminfo?` then `viminfo=%,'100,<50,s10,h`

Comment: @Aminopterin There you have it: `:h viminfo-%`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Don't you want 15 points? XD You may post as answer.

Comment: @Aminopterin okay, did so.

Comment: Beside reputation, also makes future reader easier as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by the ['viminfo'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#viminfo-%) setting containing the "%" item. If the "%" flag is included in your viminfo setting, this means:

> When included, save and restore the buffer list.  If Vim is
>    started with a file name argument, the buffer list is not
>    restored.  If Vim is started without a file name argument, the
>    buffer list is restored from the viminfo file.  Quickfix
>    ('buftype'), unlisted ('buflisted'), unnamed and buffers on
>    removable media (viminfo-r) are not saved.
>    When followed by a number, the number specifies the maximum
>    number of buffers that are stored.  Without a number all
>    buffers are stored.

Comment: I think there should be best a warning that tells the user not to copy other's vimrc mindlessly XD Originally my vimrc was littered with whatever I copied from other people, in the very start of my learning Vim. That way, I had spent many hours debugging strange things.